# How to enforce authentication for all resources?

Tags: admin, authentication

I want to host a personal journal with wordpress. I don't want to share it with 3rd parties but I want to be able to access it from anywhere with my admin credentials. 
There are several plugins around which all do nothing but protect access to sites/posts - but everything else (`/wp-content/` first and foremost) is still accessible without permissions.

So what I basically want is a check like for `/wp-admin` is required for each resource on my blog.

```
${SITE_URL}/.*
```

I know that I could just add some `.htaccess` basic authentication. But I want to avoid that.

Comment: *"I don't want to share it with the public"* - what about running it locally?

Comment: @birgire - i don't want to share it with 3rd parties but want to be able to access it from everywhere with my admin credentials.

Comment: Do you want to serve your uploads from a non public folder through PHP with a WordPress login?

Comment: @birgire I basically just want to add the `auth_redirect()` function before accessing `/wp-content/*`

Answer (score 0):

You should define which resources you want to protect. I think you have such choices:

1) Protect whole site

2) Protect only posts (without resources)

3) Protect posts & all resources (but only `uploads`, not `wp-content`! otherwise you will break your themes/plugins)

So, as you say you need 3rd way. In such case, you should use `htaccess` cookie-based redirection:

- Create `htaccess` in `wp-content/uploads` which restricts access to all urls there for users who doesn't have a cookie "cookie_name" set to value i.e. 'xyz':

  `RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=xyz; [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://your_site.com/authorization-page [NC,L]`
- Create `authorization-page` where should be a form to insert a password (set whatever you want) and if user correctly enters password, then set  cookie `cookie_name` to `xyz`.

p.s. just replace `xyz` and `cookie_name` with very random characters.